# How to write a password strength testing program in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am very new to Haskell, and I found some exercises on the internet, and one of them asks to write a program that takes a String and  checks if the word has at least 8 characters, 1 uppercase letter, and 1 digit. In case it does, it returns true.
However I have absolutely no idea what to do.
I have tried to work with a Lambda expressions but I think it's not the way to go.

Would appreciate some help,
Thanks

Comment: Take a look at `all`, `any`, `isUpper` and `isLower`.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, which exercise set are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest something like this.

```
import Data.Char

checkPassword :: String -> Bool
checkPassword xs = all (\f -> f xs) [checkOneDigit, checkOneUppercase, checkLength]
    where checkOneDigit xs = (== 1) $ length $ filter isDigit xs
          checkOneUppercase xs = (== 1) $ length $ filter isUpper xs
          checkLength xs = (>= 8) $ length xs
```

Comment: I think one uppercase should be read as *at least* one uppercase... Perhaps using `any` is then a better idea.

Comment: Hey Daniel, welcome to stackoverflow! Thanks for your answer. I just wanted to say,  especially since the OP is asking for help with an exercise, I feel like this is not a helpful answer. The OP is not in need of a password checker, they are mainly trying to *learn how* to program in Haskell. I like to give enough information to 'unblock' the person, whatever they need to start making progress again (say, point them to the `any` function and give an example). Or if you *must* provide a complete solution, use it as an opportunity to talk about an interesting concept or approach.